# how to load phtml in static block with loading data from custom module block for fetching current logged in information magento 2?

Tags: magento2

Actually i am trying like this

> mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\Block\Index\Current.php

```
<?php
namespace Inkind\Navdata\Block\Index;
class Current extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template
{ 
    private $_objectManager; 
    protected $_customerSession; 
    protected $_customer; 
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\ObjectManagerInterface $objectmanager, 
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession, 
        \Magento\Customer\Model\Customer $customer
    ){
        $this->_objectManager = $objectmanager; 
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession; 
        $this->_customer = $customer; 
        parent::__construct($context);
    }

   public function getCurrentCustomer() 
    { 
    echo "Test";die;
        $context = $this->_objectManager->get('Magento\Framework\App\Http\Context'); 
        $isLoggedIn = $context->getValue(\Magento\Customer\Model\Context::CONTEXT_AUTH); 
        $customerSession = $this->_objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\SessionFactory')->create(); 
        echo "1";
        if ($isLoggedIn == 1) { 
        echo "2";
            $customer_id = $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId(); 
            $customerData = $this->_customer->load($customer_id); 
            $data['name'] = $customerData->getName();
            $data['email'] = $customerData->getEmail();
            //return $data; 
        } 
    } 

        /* public function getCustomerName(){
        return $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getName();
    } */



}
```

> mage\app\code\Inkind\Navdata\view\frontend\templates\content.phtml

```
<?php
    $block->getCurrentCustomer();

    //echo $block->getCustomerName();
    //var_dump($customerData);
    //echo $customerData->getName(); 
    //echo $customerData->getEmail(); 
    /* if($isLoggedIn) {
       $customerSession = $objectManager->get('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
        $customerSession->getCustomer()->getId();  
        $name =   $customerSession->getCustomer()->getName(); 
        $email=  $customerSession->getCustomer()->getEmail(); 
        $customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();  
        $customer_logged_in = $customerSession->isLoggedIn();


    } */

?>
```

Now i am calling this block with phtml file like below shown

```
{{block class="Inkind\Navdata\Block\Index" template="Inkind_Navdata::content.phtml"}}
```

Comment: Any error do you face? Or what you are looking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your line of code in CMS block like this.

```
{{block class="Inkind\Navdata\Block\Index\Current" template="Inkind_Navdata::content.phtml"}}
```

Comment: If answer help you, please mark as solution and upvote. So it help other in community.